# Reading Assembly version information of WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, assemblies, version

I am reading version information of my wpf application, but I am not getting the correct version as I have write in `AssemblyInfo.cs` file. In my file there is

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.1.001")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("0.0.001")]
```

I am reading version information using this code

```
 System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

I am getting this version `0.1.1.0` and it should be `0.1.001`

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The properties `Major`, `Minor`, `Build` and `Revision` of class `Version` are of type `int`, not `string`. So when string from assembly version is parsed into `Version` class, the parts of this string will be converted to int representation. Also there are rule that first number of specified version string is `Major` component of `Version`:

```
"1" - 1.0.0.0
"1.2" - 1.2.0.0
"1.2.3" - 1.2.3.0
"1.2.3.4" 1.2.3.4
```

Comment: In other words, the leading zeros cannot be part of the version value. If you want to show them you'll have to format a string manually.

Answer (score 3):

In the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), it says that:

> All components of the version must be integers greater than or equal to 0

So it's either rounding up or removing trailing zeros to get a valid integer.