# Published version WPF .NET Core

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, .net-core, clickonce

I am looking to use code similar to the below, but in a .NET Core WPF C# application. This is what I previously used.

```
public static string GetVersion()
{
   if (System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
   {
      Version myVersion = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion;
      return $"Version {myVersion}";
   }
   return "Version not deployed";
}
```

Is there an equivalent in .NET Core?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [a closed issue](https://github.com/dotnet/deployment-tools/issues/9) around this issue and *ClickOnce* deployment.

> `ApplicationDeployment` class is not available - that class is implemented in `System.Deployment assembly` that is **not part of .NET Core 3.1 or .NET 5**.
>
> We will have a way to expose some of the properties that the class enables, i.e. URL parameters and update status. But, that work could not be completed for .NET 5 release. We will enable it in one of .NET 6 previews. Here are the tracking issues: #27 and #53
>
> Use of `ApplicationDeployment` class in your deployed ClickOnce application is not possible, but main ClickOnce experience is available. It includes: creating ClickOnce deployment (manifests), publishing the application, creating and publishing updates. Your application will get automatic update check (and update, if user accepts it) - this part is handled by ClickOnce runtime and the new Launcher tool that becomes the entry point of ClickOnce deployment for .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5 applications.

Consequently, as for now there does not seem to be a way to do this in .NET Core directly.

Comment: And how can it be done indirectly?

Comment: @IstvanHeckl What I mean is that this is not built into the framework.

Comment: Ok, I get it is not in the framework. But what is the alternative? I still want to display the CurrentVersion, I also want to display the CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory (so the users now where is the mdf file). To solve the first problem I could hard code a string and change it when there is a new version (not nice). For the second problem I have not idea.

Answer (score 4):

There has been some progress on this in .NET. According to a [comment](https://github.com/dotnet/deployment-tools/issues/27#issuecomment-1310551298) by a Microsoft employee you can now detect these values via environment variables as is done [in mage.exe](https://github.com/dotnet/deployment-tools/blob/dfb0a98c68da39fc9cd1d82e200a19badf4e7112/Documentation/dotnet-mage/ApplicationDeployment.cs#L50). For example something like this:

```
bool.TryParse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClickOnce_IsNetworkDeployed"), out bool isNetworkDeployed);
Version.TryParse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClickOnce_CurrentVersion"), out Version currentVersion);
```

Most of the discussion on that GitHub issue is about .NET 7. On the other hand, some comments suggest this code has its own independent release schedule. I don't know enough to say if/when it will be available in Core.

Comment: Nice idea, but check if it works in your custom case! . . . . . For me it does not work and always `False` is returned. (.NET Core 3.1, created ClickOnce setup with `vsbuild` (msbuild) inside of an Azure build pipeline instead of `mage.exe`)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to get the assembly version using  System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version, as shown in
[Reading Assembly version information of WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546691/reading-assembly-version-information-of-wpf-application)

For more click-once capabilities not ported to .net core3.1/5/6, look here https://github.com/derskythe/WpfSettings

Comment: But that's the assembly version (`<AssemblyVersion>` in your SDK-style .csproj file). This is not necessarily the same as the ClickOnce publish version (`<ApplicationVersion>` in your .pubxml file).